# SQLite return "row value misused" error at compile sql

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I get the following error when compiling the following query:

```
String sql = "select fecha, sexo, count(*) as cantidad from datos where datos.muncode='" + muncode + "' group by(fecha, sexo) order by(fecha) asc";
    Cursor c = session.getDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
```

-->> SQLiteException: row value misused (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Answer (score 3):

Remove parentheses from `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`

Comment: thanks for the answer, with that I solved the error